# python - bz2 not recompressing properly

Tags: python, hex, byte, bz2

The following code is able to read in a bzipped file:

```
offset = 24

# Open the object
fobj = open(filey,'rb')

# Read the data
buffer = fobj.read()

# Apply bz2 compression
buffer_unbzip,places_to_bzip = bzip_blocks_decompress_all(buffer,offset)
```

where the bzip_blocks_decompress_all function is defined as below:

```
def bzip_blocks_decompress_all(data,offset):
    import bz2
    frames = bytearray()
    places_to_bzip = []
    while offset < len(data):
        block_cmp_bytes = abs(int.from_bytes(data[offset:offset + 4], 'big', signed=True))
        offset += 4
        frames += bz2.decompress(data[offset:offset + block_cmp_bytes])
        places_to_bzip.append([offset,offset+block_cmp_bytes])
        offset += block_cmp_bytes
        
    return frames,places_to_bzip
```

So I have the locations of where objects are bzipped (places_to_bzip). So my thinking is that we should be able to do something like the following:

```
# Try to compress using bz2 just based on some of the places_to_bzip
a1 = buffer[places_to_bzip[0][0]:places_to_bzip[0][1]]
a2 = buffer_unbzip[places_to_bzip[0][0]:places_to_bzip[0][1]]

# Convert a2 back to a1 with a bzip compression
a3 = bz2.compress(a2)
print(len(a1))
print(len(a2))
print(len(a3))

104
104
70
```

Why is this not recompressing properly? Below is the output from a1 and a2 for testing:

```
print(a1)
b'BZh51AY&SY\xe6\xb1\xacS\x00\x00\x02_\xab\xfe(@\x00\x10\x00@\x04\x00@\x00@\x800\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00@\x08\x00\x00\x18 \x00T4\x8d\x004\x01\xa0\x91(\x01\x90\xd3\xd2\x14\xac\xd6v\x85\xf0\x0fD\x85\xc3A}\xe09\xbc\xe1\x8b\x04Y\xbfb$"\xcc\x13\xc0B\r\x99\xf1Qa%S\x00|]\xc9\x14\xe1BC\x9a\xc6\xb1L'

print(a2)
bytearray(b'\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x05z\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002\x04@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002\x04@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Your expectation that the recompressed data (`a3`) will match the original compressed data (`a1`) in size is potentially flawed; due to the non-deterministic nature of the compression process and possible differences in compression context and settings, you will have to make absolutely sure that the conditions, context, compression level, algorithm, and data and headers are all identical in order to make sure it compresses down to the same exact bytes. Have you ruled all those possible issues out yet?

Comment: `buffer_unbzip` contains the decompressed data only, and offsets in `places_to_bzip` are the start/end offsets of slices in the original compressed data.  How does slicing `buffer_unbzip` with those offsets make any sense?

Comment: `places_to_bzip` would be better named `places_to_unbzip` considering the content.  The offset of the unbzipped frames is not known.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comments, `buffer_unbzip` contains the decompressed data only, and offsets in `places_to_bzip` are the start/end offsets of slices in the original compressed data.  The offset of the unbzipped frames is not known.

Below I've reverse-engineered the input file and generated one, then used the OP's code to extract the data.  The code is modified to also return the start/end of each unbzipped frame and then walks the offsets re-compressing and comparing each frame's compression data:

```py
import bz2
import struct

### Reproducible input file example ###
def write_frame(f, data):
    bzdata = bz2.compress(data)
    # Write size of compressed data as big-endian 4-byte integer,
    # then the compressed data.
    f.write(struct.pack('>L', len(bzdata)) + bzdata)

with open('file.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'A' * 24)  # header in the original data?
    write_frame(f, b'B' * 50)  # compressed frames
    write_frame(f, b'C' * 25)
    write_frame(f, b'D' * 30)
    write_frame(f, b'E' * 12)
### END ###

offset = 24

# Open the object
with open('file.bin','rb') as fobj:
    # Read the data
    buffer = fobj.read()

def bzip_blocks_decompress_all(data,offset):
    import bz2
    frames = bytearray()
    places_to_bzip = []
    places_to_unbzip = []
    while offset < len(data):
        # Why signed and abs()?  A length should never be negative.
        # Note: >L means big-endian 4-byte unsigned integer.
        #       A tuple of the struct elements is returned,
        #       in this case a 1-tuple, so [0] to get the integer
        block_cmp_bytes = struct.unpack_from('>L', data, offset)[0]
        #block_cmp_bytes = abs(int.from_bytes(data[offset:offset + 4], 'big', signed=True))
        offset += 4
        start = len(frames)
        frames += bz2.decompress(data[offset:offset + block_cmp_bytes])
        end = len(frames)
        places_to_bzip.append([start, end])
        places_to_unbzip.append([offset, offset + block_cmp_bytes])
        offset += block_cmp_bytes
        
    return frames, places_to_bzip, places_to_unbzip

# Apply bz2 compression
buffer_unbzip, places_to_bzip, places_to_unbzip = bzip_blocks_decompress_all(buffer, offset)
print(f'{buffer=}')
print(f'{buffer_unbzip=}')

# Try to compress using bz2 just based on some of the places_to_bzip
for (bstart, bend), (unbstart, unbend) in zip(places_to_bzip, places_to_unbzip):
    a1 = buffer[unbstart:unbend]
    a2 = buffer_unbzip[bstart:bend]

    # Convert a2 back to a1 with a bzip compression
    a3 = bz2.compress(a2)
    print(a1 == a3, a2)
```

Output:

```
buffer=b"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x00\x00\x00'BZh91AY&SY?\xbf\xc2\x8b\x00\x00\x02\x14\x00\x00\x01\x10\x00 \x00!\x00\x82\x0b\x17rE8P\x90?\xbf\xc2\x8b\x00\x00\x00'BZh91AY&SY\x0b\xc7\x94'\x00\x00\x02$\x00\x02\x00\x08\x00 \x00!\x00\x82\x0b\x17rE8P\x90\x0b\xc7\x94'\x00\x00\x00'BZh91AY&SYX\xf3\xe3\x91\x00\x00\x02$\x00\x00\x10\x04\x00 \x00!\x00\x82\x0b\x17rE8P\x90X\xf3\xe3\x91\x00\x00\x00'BZh91AY&SY\xb6\xa1w{\x00\x00\x02D\x00\x00@\x02\x00 \x00!\x00\x82\x0b\x17rE8P\x90\xb6\xa1w{"
buffer_unbzip=bytearray(b'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEE')
True bytearray(b'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB')
True bytearray(b'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC')
True bytearray(b'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD')
True bytearray(b'EEEEEEEEEEEE')
```